# Sorting Log data from text file with powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, sorting, object, data-manipulation

I have a log file that looks like this

```
2019-11-12 14:25:11,538 DEBUG Calculated Value: 0.04
```

My wish is to extract the value at the end and if it is over a certain amount raise an alert (Alert code is completed)

I have written this so far

```bsh
$array = @(Get-Content C:\CR1\AllTransFilter.log) 
foreach ($line in $array) {
    $TransDate = $array.Substring(0,10)
    $TransTime = $array.Substring(11,5)
    $CalcValue = $array.Substring(48)
}
```

Now $CalcValue gives me a list of the values, I get errors though trying to turn the $CalcValue variable into a double ( I have dded .ToDouble and [Double] and get errors each time

So My questions are thus

1. Is this the correct way to approach this? I have attempted converting to CSV with custom headers but did not get far.
2. Can someone point me in the direction of some reading material (noobish?) for manipulating arrays to acheive what I need?
3. What is the best way to get the calculated value and work out if its above a set value.

Any help is greatly appreciated

EDIT

So using Lee's code

```
$InStuff = C:\Work\CR1\AllTransFilter.log
$Null = $InStuff -match '^(?<DateTime>.+),.+Calculated Value: (?<CalcValue>.+)$'
$LogLineData = [PSCustomObject]@{
    DateTime = [datetime]$Matches.DateTime
    CalcValue = [float]$Matches.CalcValue
    }

$LogLineData | Out-Host
'=' * 30
$LogLineData.DateTime | Out-Host
$LogLineData.DateTime.GetType() | Out-Host
'=' * 30
$LogLineData.CalcValue | Out-Host
$LogLineData.CalcValue.GetType() | Out-Host

$LogLineData
```

Should $logLineData retreive all lines? as it only retreives one

Sorry for the noobishness, I am slowley getting my head round it.

#

The file is a .log file and contains the following lines, a small sample is below file size ranges from 100k to 1mb

```
2019-11-12 07:58:34,684 DEBUG Calculated Value: 6.41
2019-11-12 08:00:59,823 DEBUG Calculated Value: 24.79
2019-11-12 08:02:44,364 DEBUG Calculated Value: 37.18
2019-11-12 08:06:16,075 DEBUG Calculated Value: 4.95
2019-11-12 08:08:01,202 DEBUG Calculated Value: 32.84
2019-11-12 08:28:31,369 DEBUG Calculated Value: 30.98
2019-11-12 09:29:21,013 DEBUG Calculated Value: 15.27
2019-11-12 09:31:41,489 DEBUG Calculated Value: 6.01
2019-11-12 09:58:21,990 DEBUG Calculated Value: 8.32
2019-11-12 12:13:49,691 DEBUG Calculated Value: 7.63
2019-11-12 15:03:53,459 DEBUG Calculated Value: 6.83
2019-11-12 18:48:07,583 DEBUG Calculated Value: 7.62
2019-11-12 20:23:49,272 DEBUG Calculated Value: 173.53
2019-11-13 06:49:22,654 DEBUG Calculated Value: 3.09
2019-11-13 06:50:45,921 DEBUG Calculated Value: 8.1
```

```
$InStuff = 'C:\Test\AllTransFilter.log'
foreach ($Line in $InStuff){
$line = $InStuff -match '^(?<DateTime>.+),.+Calculated Value: (?<CalcValue>.+)$'

$LogLineData = [PSCustomObject]@{
    DateTime = [datetime]$Matches.DateTime
    CalcValue = [float]$Matches.CalcValue
}   
}
$LogLineData | Out-Host
'=' * 30
$LogLineData.DateTime | Out-Host
$LogLineData.DateTime.GetType() | Out-Host
'=' * 30
$LogLineData.CalcValue | Out-Host
$LogLineData.CalcValue.GetType() | Out-Host
```

Is what I have so far, thank you Lee, which gives me the following output

```
DateTime            CalcValue
--------            ---------
12/11/2019 14:25:11      0.04


==============================

12 November 2019 14:25:11



IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     DateTime                                 System.ValueType


==============================
0.04

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Single                                   System.ValueType
```

Could you let me know how to do the foreach properly, and I have just noticed that the output does not actual exist in the log file, I pasted the same date in the sanitized output above and there is no calculated value at 14:25, so now I am really confused.

Comment: Should be `$line.Substring` rather than `$array.Substring`.

Answer (score 0):

while `Benjamin Hubbard` has pointed out the most likely source of your glitch [*grin*], the method you are using - `.SubString()` - is rather slow. if you are doing this to ***many*** lines from your log, then switching to some sort of regex for parsing is likely to be worth while. the following code uses named capture groups and the automatic variable `$Matches` to build a PSCustomObject. it also creates a `[datetime]` object instead of a date *string* and a time *string*.

---

note that this only covers getting the values into proper objects. it does NOT cover your threshold test. [*grin*]

---

what the code does ...

- fakes reading in a text file
  when you are confident that it is working correctly, replace that section [everything up to the blank line BEFORE the `foreach`] with a `Get-Content` call to load your real file instead of the test data.
- iterates thru the resulting collection of lines of text
- runs a regex match on the line to generate named capture groups
  those are automatically stored in the automatic variable `$Matches`.
- builds a `[PSCustomObject]` with the desired properties
  if you want the date & time in different props, you will need to modify the regex OR calculate the two items independently.
- converts the datetime *string* into a datetime *object*
- assigns that to the proper property [*grin*]
- does the same with the calculated value data
- sends the new custom object out to the `$Results` collection
- display that collection on screen

at that point, you can gracefully work on the values as needed.

here's the code ...

```
# fake reading in a text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$InStuff = @'
2019-11-12 07:58:34,684 DEBUG Calculated Value: 6.41
2019-11-12 08:00:59,823 DEBUG Calculated Value: 24.79
2019-11-12 08:02:44,364 DEBUG Calculated Value: 37.18
2019-11-12 08:06:16,075 DEBUG Calculated Value: 4.95
2019-11-12 08:08:01,202 DEBUG Calculated Value: 32.84
2019-11-12 08:28:31,369 DEBUG Calculated Value: 30.98
2019-11-12 09:29:21,013 DEBUG Calculated Value: 15.27
2019-11-12 09:31:41,489 DEBUG Calculated Value: 6.01
2019-11-12 09:58:21,990 DEBUG Calculated Value: 8.32
2019-11-12 12:13:49,691 DEBUG Calculated Value: 7.63
2019-11-12 15:03:53,459 DEBUG Calculated Value: 6.83
2019-11-12 18:48:07,583 DEBUG Calculated Value: 7.62
2019-11-12 20:23:49,272 DEBUG Calculated Value: 173.53
2019-11-13 06:49:22,654 DEBUG Calculated Value: 3.09
2019-11-13 06:50:45,921 DEBUG Calculated Value: 8.1
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine

$Results = foreach ($IS_Item in $InStuff)
    {
    $Null = $IS_Item -match '^(?<DateTime>.+),.+Calculated Value: (?<CalcValue>.+)$'

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        DateTime = [datetime]$Matches.DateTime
        CalcValue = [float]$Matches.CalcValue
        }
    }

$Results
```

output ...

```
DateTime               CalcValue
--------               ---------
2019-11-12 7:58:34 AM       6.41
2019-11-12 8:00:59 AM      24.79
2019-11-12 8:02:44 AM      37.18
2019-11-12 8:06:16 AM       4.95
2019-11-12 8:08:01 AM      32.84
2019-11-12 8:28:31 AM      30.98
2019-11-12 9:29:21 AM      15.27
2019-11-12 9:31:41 AM       6.01
2019-11-12 9:58:21 AM       8.32
2019-11-12 12:13:49 PM      7.63
2019-11-12 3:03:53 PM       6.83
2019-11-12 6:48:07 PM       7.62
2019-11-12 8:23:49 PM     173.53
2019-11-13 6:49:22 AM       3.09
2019-11-13 6:50:45 AM        8.1
```

Comment: @CarlosFandango - without seeing a sample of the file & the code in question, i cannot tell why things are failing.

Comment: The Code is above, and the file is the line you used, multiple times each on its own line but with a consecutive time and date and a different calculated value

Comment: @CarlosFandango - you need to iterate thru the `$InStuff` collection. the data you posted was only one line ... so the demo done with that one for only one line. [*grin*] wrap the parsing code in a `foreach` to iterate thru the collection.

Comment: I am still having issues with using the whole log file instead of the  line, the for each loops throws errorsYou cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:13 char:1
+ $LogLineData.DateTime.GetType() | Out-Host

Comment: " if you cannot be bothered to add such to your Question, why do you expect anyone else to do so? [frown] – Lee_Dailey" This is all very new to me, Stack Overflow that it is, I am used to just posting "Forum" style, I will try again, I have deleted the answer, again apologies.

Comment: @CarlosFandango - yep, the comment stuff is very limited - deliberately, i think. plus, questions and answers are very different things from each other AND from comments. [*grin*]

Comment: Can I ask, I edited my first post with the detail you require and what I have attempted, and it says the edit was under review, but now everythings dissapeared?

Comment: @CarlosFandango - the only edit on your question was yesterday and it is all still there. try to edit it again ...

Comment: @CarlosFandango - great! [*grin*] i will edit my answer soon-ish.

Comment: @CarlosFandango - please take a look at the **_heavily edited_** answer ... [*grin*]

Comment: Hi Lee, I can't thank you enough for your help and the break down on the code, this has helped me understand immensly, I will give it a try very soon, One last question , How do I mark it has answered?

Comment: @CarlosFandango - you are most welcome! glad to have helped a bit ... [*grin*]

Comment: LOL i Lied,I have one more question,, it worked perfectly I am just interested on $Null, Could you explain a bit more on why you use that?

Comment: @CarlosFandango - the `$Null =` is there to suppress the False/True output of the `-match` by assigning it to `nothing at all`. otherwise you would have a `True` in the info being sent to the `$Results` collection since any output that is not otherwise dealt with will end up in the output stream ... and that ends up in the `$Results` collection.

Comment: @Lee_Dailley, How do I break down the Date and Time into 2 PS objects please?

Comment: @CarlosFandango - you can either modify the regex pattern OR use the `.ToString()` method on the current `[datetime]` object. the 2nd would be something like this ... >>> `$DateTimeObject.ToString('HH:mm:ss')` <<< or this >>> `$DateTimeObject.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')` <<< ///// the 2nd options is likely best since it gives you the most flexible way to handle the  time and date info.